# An esoteric pondering regarding the lack of compatibility between % and = and <>

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I am new to the world of programming but please humor me nonetheless.

I know that % works with LIKE and NOT LIKE. For example the following two queries work:

```
--QUERY 1
SELECT *
FROM TrumpFeccandid_Pacs
WHERE PACID NOT LIKE 'C%'

--QUERY 2
SELECT *
FROM TrumpFeccandid_Pacs
WHERE PACID LIKE 'C%'
```

However % does not work with = or <>. For example, the following two queries do not work:

```
--QUERY A
SELECT * 
FROM TrumpFeccandid_Pacs 
WHERE PACID <> 'C%'

--QUERY B
SELECT *
FROM TrumpFeccandid_Pacs
WHERE PACD = 'C%'
```

Why is this the case? Intuitively speaking I feel like not only should queries A and B work but Query A should be equivalent to Query 1 and Query B should be equivalent to Query 2.

These examples were using T-SQL from Sql Server 2016.

Comment: `=` means exact value comparison. And `Like` is for pattern of value. You can't merge both of them..

Comment: @ShakeerMirza but why is it important that `LIKE` only be for pattern of value while `=` only be fore exact value comparison

Comment: `=` is a public symbol. That has an unique meaning. The behavior of `=` operator not defined by Microsoft..

Comment: @ShakeerMirza So what you mean is that = and <> follow pre-established rules that existed before the creation of SQL?

Comment: You can find history of [history of equal sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign) here

Comment: SQL language standards are maintained by **ANSI** and **ISO**  that which every RDBMS product development should follow.. So <> these all signs are specified by ANSI..

Comment: The last two queries _do_ work, they just have different semantics. Why doesn't `42 = 'XLII'` evaluate to `TRUE`? Because of the defined semantics for the `=` operator. A common _optimistic programming_ mistake is to hope that variable values will be used as the programmer wishes, not as defined by some rigid rules. For example, why can't some of my queries use `FROM @MyTable` where the variable is not a table variable, but a string containing the name of a table? It should do what I want, not what I say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image a relatively simple query like this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.Name = B.Name
```

If `=` worked like `LIKE`, god help you if `Name` contains a percent or underscore!

Comment: Wow that is a really good point. That does make me wonder what if I wanted to do a wildcard search for something that does have % or _ in it then what would I do?

Comment: Do you mean a non-equijoin (I think that's what they're called) based on pattern matching?  Easy, `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A.Name LIKE B.Name`.

Comment: @anang If you wanted to use a wildcard character as a literal in a pattern then you would RTFM for [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) and realize that an _escape character_ can be used.

Answer (score 1):

> Intuitively speaking I feel like

That is where you go awry!

`LIKE` is *defined* a certain way, as are `=` and `<>`.  The people who designed the language presumably tried to make it accessible, to make it easy to understand and remember and use.  What they did not do, because they could not do, is define it such that it meets everyone's expectations and hunches.

Why is `LIKE` different from `=`?

- `a like 'C%'` is true if `a` starts with 'C'
- `a = 'C%'` is true if `a` is exactly the 2 letter string 'C%'

But the real moral to this story IMO is that if you want to know how the language works, the best advice is RTFM.  Especially when it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

SQL provides standard pattern matching like those used in Unix, grep, sed. These patters can be used only with operators "LIKE" and "NOT LIKE"..... 
LIKE/NOT LIKE are Boolean types i.e they returns TRUE/FALSE if the match_expression matches the specified pattern.

Following are various wild card used to match the patterns:

```
% = Any number of characters
_ = Any Single character 
[] = Any single character within the specified range 
[^] = Any single character not within the specified range
```

Documentation on patterns and like operators:
[SQL server LIKE operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)